# Groovy method that takes multiple arguments of type Maps

Tags: groovy

i have a groovy method that works with hard coded variable of `map containing maps`. I would like to make, such that the maps are passed as arguments. The number of maps will `vary` as well. A simple representation that i am trying to achieve will be like so:

```
def name(Map p...) {
 //code to loop through each of the maps 
    p.each { k ->
      "${k.first}, ${k.last}"
 //another loop with the internal map
    something { 
       k.details.each { name, value ->
  //some code
        }
   }
 }
}
```

And example of the `Map of maps` that i would need to pass as Args looks like so:

```
def persons = [
[first: 'Jack', last: 'Smith', details: [gender: 'male', Age: 25]], 
[first: 'Sean', last: 'Dean', details: [gender: 'male', Age: 26]]
]
```

Then down the line, i would like to call something like

```
name(persons)
```

how can i achieve this? My test so far in the groovyConsole isn't taking me anywhere...

Comment: Would you mind explaining the exact issue that you are stuck with?

Comment: It is appearing that pass a list `name(persons)`, not a map as defined in the method.

Comment: yes thats seems to a reason here... i overlooked it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is, that you don't have a map of maps but a list of maps. So to be able to call your method with the persons as parameter you have to change its signature to:

```
def map(List p) {
    ...
}
```

This is my snippet in the groovyConsole:

```
def persons = [
    [first: 'Jack', last: 'Smith', details: [gender: 'male', Age: 25]], 
    [first: 'Sean', last: 'Dean', details: [gender: 'male', Age: 26]]
]

class Person {
    def name(List p) {
        println p
    }
}

def p = new Person()
p.name(persons)
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're passing a `list` to `varArgs`, you have to use `*(list)` to extract each element out of the list and pass them:

Example:

```
def name( Map... p ) { 
  p.each{ println it} 
}

def persons = [
[first: 'Jack', last: 'Smith', details: [gender: 'male', Age: 25]], 
[first: 'Sean', last: 'Dean', details: [gender: 'male', Age: 26]]
]

name(*(persons))
```

Note: I am not quite sure I am using the right terminology but I hope you get the gist `:)`